# destructor for a class with a multiset container c++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, multiset

I have a class which uses a `multiset` as a container:

```
multiset<string, SortFunction> elements;
```

In the destructor, how should I erase the `multiset`? Should I delete it, or remove all the elements in it?

Comment: You should leave it alone in your destructor. It will take care of itself.

Comment: @N.M. Answers go down here: ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

Answer (score 3):

If the elements have destructors that clean themselves up properly - which `std::string` does - then you need do nothing.

The `multiset` will take care of cleaning itself, and that will clean up the elements as well.

Comment: so I don't need to add for example " elements.clear(); "  in the destructor?

Comment: @khodayarJ Yes, `you need do nothing` probably means: *don't add `elements.clear();`* here.

Comment: Yes, you *can* add an `elements.clear()` statement to the destructor.   But it is not necessary, since `multiset`'s destructor will clean up for you.

Comment: "you need do nothing", in the English language, means "there is nothing you need to do" rather than "you must do nothing" or "you must not do anything"

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ Standard (12.4 Destructors)

> 8 After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any
>   automatic objects allocated within the body, a destructor for class X
>   **calls the destructors for X’s direct non-variant non-static data 
>   members**....

So the destructor of your class will call the destructor of the multiset that in turn will call destructors of its element before freeing the allocated memory for the elements.

Comment: It is not that the class destructor will call the destructor of `multiset`.   It is that the process of destroying an instance of the class sequentially invokes the destructor of the class, then invokes the destructors of members, and then does the same for base classes.

Comment: @Peter  Do you not agree with the quote from the C++ Standard?

Answer (score 0):

No need to do anything, when elements get deleted all the associative elements will de deleted as well (including functor you used), like in example below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct CompFunctor: std::less<T> {
    ~CompFunctor() {
        std::cout << "CompFunctor is deleted " << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    {
        std::set<std::string, CompFunctor<std::string>> m;
        m.insert("a");
        m.insert("a");
        m.insert("b");
        std::cout << "!!! start !!!" << std::endl;
    } //  m is deleted.
    std::cout << "!!! end !!!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```